# Use the TDS Remoting feature of the CData ODBC Driver for mongodb to set up a linked server for MongoDB data

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, cdata-drivers

I installed the CData ODBC Driver for MongoDB to make the application that can access SQL Server connect to mongodb.
  According to the official document,I have configured the system DSN. 
Then I modified the config file 'CData.ODBC.MongoDB.Remoting.ini' config file screenshot:-

[image]

,in which the users and passwords  was the same as what I typed in DSN.
  I started `CData.ODBC.MongoDB.Remoting.exe` and the console printed

> Test connection successful. CData ODBC Driver For MongoDB 2015
>   remoting server starts.Local port :3309.

But when I created a linked server from SQL Server Management Studio linked server info

[image]

,it showed that the user 'noobwulei' login failed.
  I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the console output, looks like the remoting service isn't running on the expected port:

> ... Local port :3309.

According to the Help documentation (http://cdn.cdata.com/help/DGB/odbc/pg_cli.htm) the executable runs the MySQL daemon by default.

In order to run the TDS daemon, you will need to run the executable from the command line and pass `TDS` as the protocol option (`-t`):

```
\> CData.ODBC.MongoDB.Remoting.exe -t TDS
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!.It does work.I thought the port 3309 was which the application CData.ODBC.MongoDB.Remoting.exe run on

Comment: I connected successfully.But I got a new problem .There is no data returned and no error after I executed the query

Comment: It sounds like you've got a different question now. I'd suggest starting a new StackOverflow question or reaching out directly to the CData Software support team (support AT cdata DOT com).